# Ajax post to controller action with C# object in parameters

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Controller action:

```
public IHttpActionResult Add(User user)
    {
        userService.Add(user);

        return Ok();
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/api/users',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ user: { FirstName: firstName, LastName: lastName, org: org} })
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("Create failed!");
        });
```

User class

```
public class User
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Organization { get; set; }
}
```

A bit new to MVC.  What am I missing to pass the ajax data into the User C# object?  Right now the controller method is being successfully called by Ajax but all the model properties are empty.  Changing the controller method is not an option.

Comment: this solution did not work for me

Comment: It should have done. Check the console for new errors with that fix in place

Comment: Yeah I made an additional mistake.  It works now, thank you!